# Why do all divs have the same name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to delete after clicking the product button, but it does not work properly I do not know why. It does not remove the correct object from the table

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'removeItem') {
    var divWithItem = document.getElementsByClassName('containerBasket__allProducts__product');
    
    // Pobieram name itemu
    var nameItem = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('name');
    var thisItemDiv = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    var thisItem = JSON.parse(products[nameItem]);
    
    products.splice(thisItem, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify(products));
    thisItemDiv.remove();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < divWithItem.length; j++) {
        divWithItem[j].setAttribute('name', [j]);
      }
    }
    console.log(products);
  }
});
```

Before looping

[image]

After looping

[image]

Why does a div with the same name?

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the snippet feature of SO.

Comment: Why are you setting the value `[i]` and not just `i`?

Comment: The nested loops make no sense either. The last iteration of the outer loop will overwrite all that was done before. Maybe you should just explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: First you set **all** divs to name `i` using i==0. Then you set **all** divs to name `i` using i==1, etc, etc. During the inner loop `j`, the value of `i` is constant and does not change.